# Representations of the SUSY algebra

Tags: supersymmetry, representation-theory

I am currently reading Wess & Bagger, and have trouble with a statement they make about representations.

If we wish to study massive, one-particle representations of the SUSY algebra, we boost to $P_m=(-M,0,0,0)$ and the algebra takes the form,

$$\{Q^A_\alpha,\bar{Q}_{\dot\beta B}\} = 2M \delta_{\alpha\dot\beta} \delta^A_B$$
with all others vanishing, where $A,B=1,\dots,N$. If we rescale the generators by $(2M)^{-1/2}$ we get,
$$\{a^A_\alpha,a^{B\dagger}_\beta\} = \delta^\beta_\alpha \delta^A_B$$
which is the algebra of $2N$ fermionic creation and annihilation operators. Thus states are built as,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} a^{A_1\dagger}_{\alpha_1} \dots a^{A_N\dagger}_{\alpha_N} \Omega$$

for a Clifford vacuum $\Omega$. Now is where I have trouble. Take $N=1$, then we have the space of states spanned by,

$$\Omega, \quad a^\dagger_\alpha \Omega, \quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}a^\dagger_\alpha a^\dagger_\beta \Omega.$$

This is said to be the "fundamental representation," but how can that be deduced/shown? Furthermore, how can one show that the first two have spin 0 and the last has spin $\frac{1}{2}$ rigorously by computation?

I should state I learnt representation theory from a maths perspective very formally (enveloping algebras, Verma modules, etc) so I fail to see the connection in physics language.

Comment: 1. Forget the technical meaning of "fundamental representation" when you encounter it in physics. It usually means little more than "the easiest/most natural representation you can find", though this often coincides with it actually being a fundamental representation in the mathematical sense. 2. What trouble exactly do you have in figuring out what representation of the Lorentz algebra (which is what having a certain spin means) the states transform in?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't know how to act on the states since the representation is not actually given - it's a map to the endomorphism group of the vector space spanned by the states, but this is not discussed in the book.

Comment: The representation is given implicitly since you should know how the Lorentz algebra acts on the $a^\dagger_\alpha$.